# Fix unable get socket.io laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I run it on localhost, everything works fine. However, when using a VPS (Ubuntu - Nginx), I encounter the error 'GET https://example.com:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR.' Even though I have added the port and SSL, it still functions normally at https://example.com. Here is the code:

```
<script src="//{{ Request::getHost() }}:{{ env('LARAVEL_ECHO_PORT') }}/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="{{ url('/js/laravel-echo-setup.js') }}"></script>
```

And in laravel-echo-setup.js:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
window.laravel_echo_port = 6001;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "socket.io",
    host: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.laravel_echo_port,
});
```

Comment: Maybe a certificate problem?

Comment: What if you remove the protocol `window.location.protocol + "//" +`?

Comment: What's your VPS setup? Are you behind a proxy/load balancer?

Comment: When I remove the protocol window.location.protocol, I still encounter the same error. I am not using any proxies or similar configurations.

Comment: Can you share you error image, I also did a laravel web socket with this config for deployment, you can check here: [link](https://github.com/tranvanhieu01012002/front-end-vue-bap/blob/master/src/services/laravelEchoService.ts)